# How to use SOAP::RPC::Driver with basic http authentication with SOAP4r

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, http-authentication, soap4r

I am generating the stubs in runtime with `driver=SOAP::RPC::Driver.new wsdl_path`. How should I initialize/configure the driver in order to use http basic authentication? I have tried `driver.options["protocol.http.basic_auth"] = [endpoint_url,'username','password']]`, though, it fails...

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have tried to use the `driver.options['protocol.http.basic_auth]#<<` method instead of **#=**. it works with **#<<**